# About the essential infimum of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I want to prove or disprove the following claim:
 $$1/\sup f=\inf(1/f)$$ in order to solve the following exercise but I don't know how to prove it!

[image]

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: Measure And Integral an introduction to  Real analysis - Wheeden and Zygmund, chapter8 exercise 9.

Comment: Are you asking how to prove ${1 \over \sup_x f(x)} = \inf_x { 1 \over f(x)}$ or how to solve the Exercise?

Comment: I want ask  how to solve the Exercise.

Comment: Is $|\cdot|$ meant to be the measure of the enclosed set?

Comment: |⋅| meant it is measurable. My idea is: If "claim" is true, we can use calim to prove the exercise. But I but I don't know how to prove the "calim"!

Answer (score 1):

Neither claim is true (I suspect that the problem should have $f(x) \ge 0$ instead).

Take $f(x) = -1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ which is measurable and $f(x) \le 0$.

We have $\sup_x f(x) = 0$ and $\inf_x {1 \over f(x) } = -1$.

We also have $\operatorname{ess} \inf_x f(x) = -1$, and $\operatorname{ess} \sup_x {1 \over f(x)} = +\infty$, hence ${1 \over \sup_x {1 \over f(x)}} = 0$.